# R match values of a dataframe with column names of another one

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I'm new with R. I need a faster way of matching two dataframes, as they are really extensive. Here is an example of what I want to do.

```
clients <- c('client1', 'client2', 'client3')
prod1 <- c(1,0,2)
prod2 <- c(0,3,1)
prod3 <- c(2,0,1)
df1 <- data.frame(clients, prod1, prod2, prod3)

client1 <- c('prod1', 'prod2', 'prod3')
client2 <- c('prod2', 'prod1', 'prod3')
client3 <- c('prod1', 'prod3', 'prod2')
df2 <- data.frame(client1, client2, client3)
```

I want to check in df2 if each client has purchased the product and delete the product names where there is a 0 in df1. The output should be something like this:

```
client1 <- c('prod1', 0, 'prod3')
client2 <- c('prod2', 0, 0)
client3 <- c('prod1', 'prod3', 'prod2')
df3 <- data.frame(client1, client2, client3)
```

So far I've only been able to do it with a match function and go 1 by 1 checking if the matching position is 0 and then replacing. I was wondering if there is a more effective way to do it as I have thousands of clients and thousands of products. Thank you very much, I'm struggling a lot with this.

Comment: I would recommend considering a different data structure here, because it is very tricky to work with, and ultimately it seems like you are just interested in seeing which products were purchased by which clients, which generally speaking is a very simple R operation.  That said, here is a loop that will create your version of `df3` - it assumes `df3` is initially defined as a copy of `df2`: `for(col in ncol(df3)){df3[,col][df3[,col] %in% colnames(df1)[which(subset(df1, clients == paste("client", col, sep = '')) == 0)]] <- 0}`

Comment: Like Erik says, you're trying to achieve an interesting data structure. More intuitively, I'd do something like this: `reshape2::melt(df1) %>% dplyr::mutate(Purchased = ifelse(value > 0, "YES", "NO"))`, giving you a binary tag for whether a client purchased a product.